# Article in Joomla displaying incorrectly

Tags: joomla3.0

[image]

So I have set them all to off but it's displaying everything, does anyone have any idea what this could be.

[image: This is really bugging me]

Comment: It could be a template override for the article view

Answer (score 2):

Start by checking the menu settings that calls the article and/or the category settings to which the article belongs.